# Http Put and querystring

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I have two problems.  I am trying to interact with a Web API that is wanting a HTTP PUT.  I am trying to pass the parameters as part of the querystring.  Unfortunately, I am not really sure how to do that.  Do I include them in with the first parameter of the PutAsync method as shown below?

The other question I have is I am unsure what needs to be coded for the HTTPContent object when using the PutAsync method.  I am trying to pass the parameters in the querystring instead of other methods that might be used.  Most of the examples that I can find are passing the data as json.

```
using (var apiManagementSystem = new HttpClient())
{
    apiManagementSystem.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://thedomain.com/api/");
    apiManagementSystem.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();
    apiManagementSystem.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("SessionID", _sessionID);

    HttpContent httpContent = new   /* What do I do Here? */
    responseMessage = apiManagementSystem.PutAsync("Product/someID?available=N", httpContent).Result;
}
```

My finished url should be something like this.

```
https://thedomain.com/api/Product/someID?available=N
```

This API that I am communicating with is a Rest API

Comment: I suspect you will need to format the request as you would POST, with form data rather than a query string.

Comment: Show the target action that the request is suppose to hit.

Comment: It is possible to pass a query string to a Put/Post type request but generally not recommended.  If possible I would create a wrapper class and put your data in there and just pass that instead.

Comment: You have to determine how the API you are interacting with expects parameter values to be passed. If it is a SOAP service, they are most likely expected as parameters in the SOAP envelope, if a REST API, probably as the last part of the URL, if it is some kind of "roll your own" design who knows. Consult the API documentation if there is any, if there is not, see if there is a blog or wiki or something.

Comment: @Kevin Updated that this is a rest API.  Thanks

Comment: In that case, it is probably wanting something like... https://thedomain.com/api/Product/someID/available/N

Comment: @Kevin I can try that however I am uncertain what I do with the HttpContent object

Comment: Most usually, unless you are passing a file or something to the API you don't need any content.

Comment: See if the PutAsync method will allow you to pass null or new HttpContent() for that parameter. Again, for a definitive answer you'll need to consult whatever documentation there is for the API in question.

Comment: @Kevin I set HttpContent to null and I get a 400.  Which is what I have been getting either that or a 405.  I have reached out to try to get better documentation.  Thanks